# How to configure Honeywell combine W2/AUX/E terminal for Emergency heat?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, central-heating, heat-pump

I have a Honeywell RTH9585WF1012 to control my forced air furnace system which has:

- Cool: 1-stage heat pump
- Heat: 1-stage heat pump (same) + **Expensive**
  emergency gaz heat from furnace.

Older thermostat had W2 which was empty and E that was used to trigger Emergency heat. Emergency heat was only used when the thermostat was put Emergency Heat manually, for example when repairing the heat pump.

Brand new thermostat has this combined W2/AUX/E terminal so I have to connect E wire to it and configure the thermostat with Aux/E heat available. In this configuration the W2/AUX/E is triggered all the time, for example after 10 minutes of normal heat pump operation, it starts the emergency heat as if it was a auxiliary.

How can I configure the thermostat's terminal W2/AUX/E to be E only? My system does not have 2-stage or auxiliary heat but only Emergency heat. My 20 year-old thermostats had separate W2/Aux and E so how can I replicate this on the new modern Honeywell thermostat?